# callback function removes two items instead of single one

Tags: javascript

What is wrong here:

```
function deluser() {
    var id = $('.nameact').attr('data-id');
    $.post('users-pro-del.php', {id}, function(data) {
        $('.nameact').remove();
        $('.namesingle').eq(0).addClass('nameact');
    });
}
```

`users-pro-del.php` - deletes a user from database.

So I want to remove the corresponding item from screen
`$('.nameact').remove();`

And give the `active` status to another (the first) item:
`$('.namesingle').eq(0).addClass('nameact');`

Sometimes it works fine.

But more often - `$('.namesingle').eq(0)` is also removed !

As I can see in console - there is only one single `.nameact` at each moment.

Any help?

Comment: Is the new `.namesingle` also deleted from the database?

Comment: @Michel, no, on `php` side everything is fine. Also, after reloading the page - `$('.namesingle').eq(0)` - is again there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax has asynchronous nature. id = $('.nameact') before $.post may be differ from the $('.nameact') after ajax request. It's better to refer nameact by Id everywhere.

```
function deluser() {
var id = $('.nameact').attr('data-id');
console.log('id to delete: ' + id);
$.post('users-pro-del.php', {id}, function(data) {
    $('.nameact[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove(); // to be sure we delete the same object in php and JS
    console.log('deleted id: ' + id);
    $('.namesingle').eq(0).addClass('nameact');
});
```

}

Comment: seems it works. But... I think - asynchronous calls can happen outside of callback function,  not inside.

Comment: we send id of object, then server processes it some time, then we receive response and call callback function. It's may be long enough between sending id and calling callback (depends on server, network, ...). Nobody knows what happens during this period of time on frontend.